# Forcing a TFS API merge to use the source branch and ignore all conflicts

Tags: c#, api, tfs, branching-and-merging

I have a piece of C# code that automates some TFS server (12.0.31101.0 Tfs2013.Update4)  version control actions.
One of these is the merge from BranchA to BranchB.
I want BranchA to be used as the “truth” and all conflicts can be solved by using the latest version in BranchA.

Currently my merge looks like this:

```
GetStatus status = workspace.Merge(sourceBranch,
   destinationBranch,
   versionSpec,
   null,
   LockLevel.None,
   RecursionType.Full,
   MergeOptions.None);
```

I then pick up the  status.NumConflicts from the status object.

```
if (workspace.GetPendingChanges().Length > 0)
{
   if (conflictsFound)
   {
      ConsoleHelper.WriteLine(numberOfConflicts + " merge conflicts found! Conflicts will be resolved by using the source branch.", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
      Conflict[] objConflicts = workspace.QueryConflicts(new string[] { destinationBranch }, true);

      foreach (Conflict objConflict in objConflicts)
      {
         objConflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptTheirs;    //This will force the take source option
         workspace.ResolveConflict(objConflict);
         ConsoleHelper.WriteLine("File : " + objConflict.YourServerItemSource, ConsoleColor.Gray);
      }
         ConsoleHelper.WriteLine("All merge conflicts encountered were resolved.", ConsoleColor.Green);
   }
   TFSCommit tfsCommit = new TFSCommit();
   checkinStatus = tfsCommit.CheckIn(workspace, workItem, out checkinChangeSet);
}
```

I then loop through the Conflicts object and make use of the  `Resolution.AcceptTheirs` option.
In the test environment this worked fine, but I now bump into a TF14121:

Failure Code :

> MergeEditDeleteException | Message  : **TF14121**: The changes previously made to $/Development/Dictionaries/FileA.dict that have not been merged will be discarded by merging the deletion of $/Development/Dictionaries/FileA.dict.

I am trying to find a way to tell the API to “ignore” conflicts and use BranchA as source.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

So I found the source of the problem. In my code I was determining the success of the merge, based on the result found in the NumFailures property on the GetStatus object. 
I created the scenario exactly as Vicky said and this indeed triggers the TF14121 – thanks again @Vicky! Turns out it is indeed a warning, and nothing more.

[image]

The interesting bit is that when the TF14121 is trigged, it is registered as a failure (B) in the GetStatus object (A). When you however inspect the failures collection in the GetStatus object and have a look at the Severity property (C) of the Failure, you will see that it is of type *SeverityType.Warning*. If you continue with the check-in it works fine though.

The bottom line is that looking only at the status.NumFailures to determine if there was a failure, is maybe not the best way after all.

Answer (score 0):

The TF14121 message shows up in the following situation: In your scenario (to merge from BranchA to BranchB), some changes firstly made to **FileA.dict** in BranchA and was checked in, a changeset named C5 for example is generated; then the **FileA.dict** file is deleted and checked in, a changeset named C6 is generated. Now when merge from BranchA to BranchB, the TF14121  warning message shows up.

You can first undelete the FileA.dict file and merge again. If you still want to leave FileA.dict file deleted during merge, you need to handle this exception, and check in the merge pending changes:

```
 workspace.CheckIn(workspace.GetPendingChanges(), "Branch Merge Checkin");
```